# Fast note app for quick lookup & copy to clipboard for osx & ios?

Tags: macos, ios, copy-paste

I'm looking for a lightweight fast note app for frequently accessed notes, so that I could:

1) Rapidly copy them to my clipboard.

2) Simply view them.

3) Work & sync across osx & iOS.

Use cases:

- Looking up & copying address & post codes of work/home.
- Looking up various ID's that I use in various places (e.g my certification ID when clients ask).
- Looking up notes on keyboard shortcuts or ways of doing things for apps
- Lookup my notes for frequent bash commands with complex syntax.
- etc..

I.e, it shouldn't be focused on being fancy, just fast viewing of note & fast copy to clipboard.

This cheatsheet app seems close, but it doesn't have osx version:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cheatsheet-quick-reference/id914665829#?platform=ipad

[EDIT].

I'm fairly proficient power user, I'm aware of 'Notes' app. If you suggest it's use, please suggest how to it can resolve the request. E.g I haven't found a 'fast' way to copy note content from spotlight. (although CMD+c from spot light copies note title+content, which is close to what I need).

Comment: What’s preventing you from using the first party Notes app?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Takes too long to look things up and copy content. I have to open app, find the note, select text, copy. (Unless there is a front-end to do this faster?)

Answer (score 2):

Before searching for a 3rd party utility, I would recommend trying out Apple's built-in Notes app. It seems to satisfy your three requirements as you can copy/paste from the clipboard, view them on both macOS and iOS, and it syncs with iCloud across all your devices (plus [iCloud website](http://icloud.com)).

Checkout these links for a how-to guide on each of the listed platforms:

- iOS: [Use Notes on your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT205773)
- macOS: [Notes for Mac: Notes overview](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22608)
- iCloud: [iCloud: View notes on iCloud.com](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph12083)

Comment: I haven't found a way to rapidly copy note content to clipboard yet. If you know of a way, then the note app might be useful. (I'm aware I can cmd+c from spotlight, but this copies the title as well as content, I often want only content).

Comment: Do you use Alfred? Or Apple’s native spotlight? Alfred is completely customizable.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like it doesn't do it out of the box. Maybe with a workflow like this: http://www.packal.org/workflow/search-apple-notes but that requires a purchase of power pack and I'm not sure if I'll be able to tailor it to what I need. If you have experience with this, feel free to post an answer or maybe a few more additional pointers.